# Centering div elements horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centering the content of my webpage. Here is a trimmed version of my HTML along with all CSS relating to that HTML code.

```
<body>
<div id="foo">

    <div id="bar">
        <!-- more html -->
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#foo {
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: center;
    background: none;
    margin-top: -0.2em;
}

#foo div {
    display: inline-block;
}

#bar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -1em;
}
```

The content sticks to the upper left of the browser window. I want it to be centered horizontally and vertically. How do I achieve this?

EDIT: I wrote upper right initially, but meant upper left.

Comment: there is no such thing as `position: center`

Comment: `position` property is used to choose alternative rules for positioning elements, not to choose where to position them. Then, `position: center` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not **position:center** its **text-align:center;** to align the content in center

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sWN33/)

```
#foo {
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    background: none;
    margin-top: -0.2em;
}
```

and remove the **margin-top:-1em** it will shift the child div = bar to top and content will be hidden check the below

```
#bar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*margin-top: -1em;*/
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sWN33/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `position: center`.  You can use `position: absolute` and set the `top`/`left` properties to arrange it in the center (if it takes up the entire width you can simply use `text-align: center`)

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pq6CR/